# an efficient iterator for getting the top k minimum of a list

Tags: python, sorting, iterator, generator, minimum

i have a list of many unsorted numbers, for example :

```py
N=1000000
x = [random.randint(0,N) for i in range(N)]
```

I only want the top k minimum values, currently this is my approach

```py
def f1(x,k): # O(nlogn)
    return sorted(x)[:k]
```

This performs lots of redundant operations, as we are sorting the remaining N-k elements too. Enumerating doesn't work either:

```py
def f2(x,k): # O(nlogn)
    y = []
    for idx,val in enumerate( sorted(x) ):
        if idx == k: break
        y.append(val)
    return y
```

Verifying enumerating doesn't help:

```py
if 1 : ## Time taken = 0.6364126205444336
    st1 = time.time()
    y = f1(x,3)
    et1 = time.time()
    print('Time taken = ', et1-st1)

if 1 : ## Time taken = 0.6330435276031494
    st2 = time.time()
    y = f2(x,3)
    et2 = time.time()
    print('Time taken = ', et2-st2)
```

Probably i need a generator that continually returns the next minimum of the list, and since getting the next minimum should be `O(1)` operation, the function `f3()` should be just `O(k)` right ? 
What `GENERATOR` function will work best in this case?

```py
def f3(x,k): # O(k)
    y = []
    for idx,val in enumerate( GENERATOR ):
        if idx == k: break
        y.append(val)
    return y
```

**EDIT 1** :

> The analysis shown here are wrong, please ignore and jump to **Edit 3**

Lowest bound possible : In terms of time complexity i think this is the lower bound achievable, but as it will will augment the original list, it is
n't the solution for my problem.

```py
def f3(x,k): # O(k) Time
    y = []
    idx=0
    while idx<k:
        curr_min = min(x)
        x.remove(curr_min) # This removes from the original list
        y.append(curr_min)
        idx += 1
    return y

if 1 : ## Time taken = 0.07096505165100098
    st3 = time.time()
    y = f3(x,3)
    et3 = time.time()
    print('Time taken = ', et3-st3)
```

O(N) Time | O(N) Storage :  Best solution so far, however it requires a copy of the original list, hence resulting in `O(N)` time and storage, having an iterator that gets the next minimum, for k times, will be `O(1)` storage and `O(k)` time.

```py
def f3(x,k): # O(N) Time | O(N) Storage
    y = []
    idx=0
    while idx<k:
        curr_min = min(x)
        x.remove(curr_min)
        y.append(curr_min)
        idx += 1
    return y

if 1 : ## Time taken = 0.0814204216003418
    st3 = time.time()
    y = f3(x,3)
    et3 = time.time()
    print('Time taken = ', et3-st3)
```

**EDIT 2** :

> Thanks for pointing out my above mistakes, getting minimum of a list should be `O(n)`, not `O(1)`.

**EDIT 3** :

> Here's a full script of analysis after using the recommended solution. Now this raised more questions
>
> 1) Constructing x as a heap using `heapq.heappush` is slower than using `list.append` x to a list, then to `heapq.heapify` it ?
>
> 2) `heapq.nsmallest` slows down if x is already a heap?
>
> 3) Current conclusion : don't `heapq.heapify` the current list, then use `heapq.nsmallest`.

```py
import time, random, heapq
import numpy as np

class Timer:
    def __init__(self, description):
        self.description = description
    def __enter__(self):
        self.start = time.perf_counter()
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        end = time.perf_counter()
        print(f"The time for '{self.description}' took: {end - self.start}.")


def f3(x,k):
    y = []
    idx=0
    while idx<k:
        curr_min = min(x)
        x.remove(curr_min)
        y.append(curr_min)
        idx += 1
    return y

def f_sort(x, k):
    y = []
    for idx,val in enumerate( sorted(x) ):
        if idx == k: break
        y.append(val)
    return y

def f_heapify_pop(x, k):
    heapq.heapify(x)
    return [heapq.heappop(x) for _ in range(k)]
def f_heap_pop(x, k):
    return [heapq.heappop(x) for _ in range(k)]

def f_heap_nsmallest(x, k):
    return heapq.nsmallest(k, x)

def f_np_partition(x, k):
    return np.partition(x, k)[:k]

if True : ## Constructing list vs heap
    N=1000000
    # N= 500000
    x_main = [random.randint(0,N) for i in range(N)]
    with Timer('constructing list') as t:
        x=[]
        for curr_val in x_main:
            x.append(curr_val)
    with Timer('constructing heap') as t:
        x_heap=[]
        for curr_val in x_main:
            heapq.heappush(x_heap, curr_val)
    with Timer('heapify x from a list') as t:
        x_heapify=[]
        for curr_val in x_main:
            x_heapify.append(curr_val)
        heapq.heapify(x_heapify)
    with Timer('x list to numpy') as t:
        x_np = np.array(x)
    """
    N=1000000
        The time for 'constructing list' took: 0.2717265225946903.
        The time for 'constructing heap' took: 0.45691753178834915.
        The time for 'heapify x from a list' took: 0.4259336367249489.
        The time for 'x list to numpy' took: 0.14815033599734306. 
    """

if True : ## Performing experiments on list vs heap
    TRIALS = 10
    ## Experiments on x as list : 
    with Timer('f3') as t:
        for _ in range(TRIALS):
            y = f3(x.copy(), 30)
        print(y)
    with Timer('f_sort') as t:
        for _ in range(TRIALS):
            y = f_sort(x.copy(), 30)
        print(y)
    with Timer('f_np_partition on x') as t:
        for _ in range(TRIALS):
            y = f_np_partition(x.copy(), 30)
        print(y)
    ## Experiments on x as list, but converted to heap in place : 
    with Timer('f_heapify_pop on x') as t:
        for _ in range(TRIALS):
            y = f_heapify_pop(x.copy(), 30)
        print(y)
    with Timer('f_heap_nsmallest on x') as t:
        for _ in range(TRIALS):
            y = f_heap_nsmallest(x.copy(), 30)
        print(y)
    ## Experiments on x_heap as heap : 
    with Timer('f_heap_pop on x_heap') as t:
        for _ in range(TRIALS):
            y = f_heap_pop(x_heap.copy(), 30)
        print(y)
    with Timer('f_heap_nsmallest on x_heap') as t:
        for _ in range(TRIALS):
            y = f_heap_nsmallest(x_heap.copy(), 30)
        print(y)
    ## Experiments on x_np as numpy array : 
    with Timer('f_np_partition on x_np') as t:
        for _ in range(TRIALS):
            y = f_np_partition(x_np.copy(), 30)
        print(y)
    # 
    """
    Experiments on x as list : 
        [0, 1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 18, 18, 19, 19, 21, 22, 24, 25]
        The time for 'f3' took: 10.180440502241254.
        [0, 1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 18, 18, 19, 19, 21, 22, 24, 25]
        The time for 'f_sort' took: 9.054768254980445.
        [ 1  5  5  1  0  4  5  6  7  6  7  7 12 12 11 13 11 12 13 18 10 14 10 18 19 19 21 22 24 25]
        The time for 'f_np_partition on x' took: 1.2620676811784506.

    Experiments on x as list, but converted to heap in place : 
        [0, 1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 18, 18, 19, 19, 21, 22, 24, 25]
        The time for 'f_heapify_pop on x' took: 0.8628390356898308.
        [0, 1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 18, 18, 19, 19, 21, 22, 24, 25]
        The time for 'f_heap_nsmallest on x' took: 0.5187360178679228.

    Experiments on x_heap as heap : 
        [0, 1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 18, 18, 19, 19, 21, 22, 24, 25]
        The time for 'f_heap_pop on x_heap' took: 0.2054140530526638.
        [0, 1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 18, 18, 19, 19, 21, 22, 24, 25]
        The time for 'f_heap_nsmallest on x_heap' took: 0.6638103127479553.
        [ 1  5  5  1  0  4  5  6  7  6  7  7 12 12 11 13 11 12 13 18 10 14 10 18 19 19 21 22 24 25]
        The time for 'f_np_partition on x_np' took: 0.2107151597738266.
    """
```

Comment: [`heapq.nsmallest`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest) is O(n) for a constant number of smallest items

Comment: Getting the minimum is O(n), not O(1), btw. Getting the minimum *of a sorted list* is O(1).

Comment: [Methods for k smallest](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/k-largestor-smallest-elements-in-an-array/).  Using a heap is one of the fastest methods which is O(n + k*log(n)) for k-th smallest.   Shows Quicksort is O(n) if sorted output is not needed.

Comment: Ahh thanks for your comments, indeed, getting the minimum is `O(n)`, not `O(1)`. It seems that indeed heap is the way to go.

Comment: You took my timing code but for some reason are timing the printing of the output. I know it's an inconsequential amount, but there is no reason to do that since that time is more or less independent of the algorithm that produced the results.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica `np.partition(x, k)[:k]` produced `[ 1  5  5  1  0  4  5  6  7  6  7  7 12 12 11 13 11 12 13 18 10 14 10 18 19 19 21 22 24 25]`, which may be the 30 smallest but they are not sorted, which is what I would expect of "the 30 smallest". So you should add a final sort: `return sorted(np.partition(x, k)[:k])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic problem for which the generally accepted solution is a data structure known as a `heap`. Below I have done 10 trials for each algorithm `f3` and `f_heap`. As the value for the second argument, `k`, gets larger the discrepancy between the two performances become even greater. For `k = 3`, we have algorithm `f3` taking .76 seconds and algorithm `f_heap` taking .54 seconds. But with `k = 30` these values become respectively 6.33 seconds and .54 seconds.

```
import time, random, heapq

class Timer:
    def __init__(self, description):
        self.description = description

    def __enter__(self):
        self.start = time.perf_counter()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        end = time.perf_counter()
        print(f"The time for {self.description} took: {end - self.start}.")


def f3(x,k): # O(N) Time | O(N) Storage
    y = []
    idx=0
    while idx<k:
        curr_min = min(x)
        x.remove(curr_min)
        y.append(curr_min)
        idx += 1
    return y


def f_heap(x, k): # O(nlogn)
    # if you do not need to retain a heap and just need the k smallest, then:
    #return heapq.nsmallest(k, x)

    heapq.heapify(x)
    return [heapq.heappop(x) for _ in range(k)]



N=1000000
x = [random.randint(0,N) for i in range(N)]

TRIALS = 10

with Timer('f3') as t:
    for _ in range(TRIALS):
        y = f3(x.copy(), 30)
print(y)

print()

with Timer('f_heap') as t:
    for _ in range(TRIALS):
        y = f_heap(x.copy(), 30)
print(y)
```

Prints:

```
The time for f3 took: 6.3301973.
[0, 1, 1, 7, 9, 11, 11, 13, 13, 14, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 20, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 25, 26, 27, 28, 28, 29, 30, 30, 31]

The time for f_heap took: 0.5372357999999995.
[0, 1, 1, 7, 9, 11, 11, 13, 13, 14, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 20, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 25, 26, 27, 28, 28, 29, 30, 30, 31]
```

[A Python Demo](https://ideone.com/Ri57Aa)

**Update**

Selecting the k smallest using `numpy.partition` as suggested by @user2357112supportsMonica is indeed very fast *if* you are already dealing with a `numpy` array. But if you are starting with an ordinary list and factor in the time to convert to an `numpy` array just to use the `numpy.partition` method, then it is slower than using `hepaq` methods:

```
def f_np_partition(x, k):
    return sorted(np.partition(x, k)[:k])


with Timer('f_np_partition') as t:
    for _ in range(TRIALS):
        x_np = np.array(x)
        y = f_np_partition(x_np.copy(), 30) # don't really need to copy
print(y)
```

The relative timings:

```
The time for f3 took: 7.2039111.
[0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 13, 14, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 18, 19, 20]

The time for f_heap took: 0.35521280000000033.
[0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 13, 14, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 18, 19, 20]

The time for f_np_partition took: 0.8379164999999995.
[0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 13, 14, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

Comment: Thinking along the line of efficiency : How should i initliase and append to `x` as a heap? instead of appending to it as a list and then converting it to a heap?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/heapq.html. If you already have a heap and you want to add another element to it, then use method `heapq.heappush`. But if you are starting with a list, then it is more efficient to build the initial heap in place with a call to `heapq.heapify` than with multiple calls to `heapq.heappush`.

Comment: I also updated my answer to show that if you only need to produce the k smallest elements of a list and then have no further need for a heap, there is `heapq.nsmallest`, which is even faster.

Comment: thanks for the advice! i tried it, and it was interesting to note that `heapq.nsmallest` is only faster if `x` isnt already a heap. see **Edit 3** for a full analysis

Comment: A heap-based option is the one most convenient with Python's standard library, but quickselect has better asymptotic complexity.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica care to elaborate how to use quickselect? perhaps show in code ?

Comment: @leonardltk1: Implementing it in Python would introduce an impractical amount of overhead, but NumPy has it as [`numpy.partition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html). With a NumPy array, you could call `numpy.partition` and then sort the part you're interested in (or skip the sort if you don't care what order you get the k minimum values in).

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Thanks!, i have updated the solution using np.partition, it seems to outperform heap in terms of conversion from list to numpy (as compared to conversion from list to heap), as well as getting the top k minimum.

But I guess the benefit of using heap is that if i were to get a list of tuples, heaps will be more flexible in terms of being able to choose which index to extract over.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica It should be pointed out that `numpy` in general derives it's speed from being implemented in the  `C` language. So there is that, too. When it comes to sorting, the quicksort *on average* outperforms the heapsort but has much poorer worst-case performance.

Comment: @leonardltk1 Yes, in my updated code where I show the use of `nsmallest`,  I do *not* first turn the list into a heap and my comment was that I would use this function only if I need the k smallest items *and* do not need a heap for other purposes.

Comment: @Booboo: NumPy uses introselect to avoid O(n^2) worst-case performance - if it's not making enough progress, it switches pivot selection to a slower method that's guaranteed to pick a good pivot. That said, NumPy does get a big benefit from being implemented in C, and in particular, from operating on raw machine data types in its inner loops. Large parts of heapq are also implemented in C, but `nsmallest` mostly isn't, and heapq doesn't get to operate on raw machine ints.

Comment: @Booboo Yeah but i was thinking on the global perspective, where one might consider constucting x as a heap to reduce the time spent obtaining the top k minimums, and it was funny how constructing x as a heap wasn't useful. Also, you can actually throw x in as a list to `np.partition` and it works slightly better too, im guessing there's some optimization done under the hood.

Comment: @leonardltk1 When I pass np.partition a `list` rather than an `np.array`, it still takes about the same amount of time, at least for `k=30`, i.e. .828 seconds.